# how to show such an under-tension geometry using the initial radiuses of the leg and the fabric in COMSOL?

Tags: geometry, simulation, comsol, materials

I am trying to model a leg wearing a sock. I want to simulate it as a cylinder (the leg) surrounded by another cylinder (the fabric) in contact with it. Before wearing the sock, its redius is smaller than the leg and after wearing, it increases because of the tensile tension acting on it. On the other hand, the leg radius decreases because of the pressure caused by the sock. Now, I am just confused about how to show such an under-tension geometry using the initial radiuses of the leg and the fabric.
Thanks for your help

I don't know how try it.